# Where can I find the currently stable RHEL sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, rhel, sshd, source

Is there any official GitHub page, that shows the current sshd_config file, used by RHEL?

Comment: Google just fails me, I cannot find it :O

Comment: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` EL8 example ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/rhel-8-beta/baseos/x86_64/Packages/openssh-server-7.8p1-3.el8.x86_64.rpm .... EL7 ex http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/Packages/openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn’t. The closest you’ll find that’s publicly accessible is the [`openssh` package repository](https://git.centos.org/rpms/openssh/); you’ll have to choose a branch then look in the `SOURCES` directory, *e.g.* [for RHEL/CentOS 8](https://git.centos.org/rpms/openssh/blob/c8/f/SOURCES).

The `sshd_config` file isn’t available as-is in the repository: it’s built by patching the original file from the OpenSSH sources. To build the file that’s installed by default, you’ll need to extract the original, then find all the patches which touch it and apply them (*e.g.* [`openssh-6.6p1-GSSAPIEnablek5users.patch`](https://git.centos.org/rpms/openssh/blob/c8/f/SOURCES/openssh-6.6p1-GSSAPIEnablek5users.patch)).